# Proving that the $2n$ Hermite polynomial is $H_{2n}(x)=(-1)^n\sum_{s=0}^{n}(-1)^{2s}(2x)^{2s}\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2s)!(n-s)!}$

Tags: hermite-polynomials

I want to prove that the $2n$ Hermite polynomial is $H_{2n}(x)=(-1)^n\sum_{s=0}^{n}(-1)^{2s}(2x)^{2s}\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2s)!(n-s)!}$

So I resort to equality:

$\begin{equation*}
H_n(x)=\sum_{s=0}^{n/2}(-1)^s\cfrac{n!}{(n-2s)!s!}(sx)^{n-2s}
\end{equation*}$

So if I substitute $2n$ in place of $n$
I get to that equality becomes:

$\begin{align*}
H_n(x)&=\sum_{s=0}^{n/2}(-1)^s\cfrac{n!}{(n-2s)!s!}(sx)^{n-2s}\\
H_{2n}(x)&=\sum_{s=0}^{2n/2}(-1)^s\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2n-2s)!s!}(sx)^{2n-2s}\\
H_{2n}(x)&=\sum_{s=0}^{n}(-1)^s\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2n-2s)!s!}(sx)^{2n-2s}\\
\end{align*}$

But then I don't know what else I can do to get the desired result (the beginning)

Or if maybe I have to use the following method:

Since $H_n(x)=(-1)^ne^{x^2}\cfrac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$ then:

$\begin{align*}
H_{2n}(x)&=(-1)^{2n}e^{x^2}\cfrac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}e^{-x^2}\\
H_{2n}(x)&=\left[(-1)^2\right]^ne^{x^2}\cfrac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}e^{-x^2}\\
H_{2n}(x)&=1^ne^{x^2}\cfrac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}e^{-x^2}\\
H_{2n}(x)&=e^{x^2}\cfrac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}e^{-x^2}\\
\end{align*}$

In which case I don't know how to find the desired result.

I really appreciate your help to know how to get to the result  $(-1)^n\sum_{s=0}^{n}(-1)^{2s}(2x)^{2s}\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2s)!(n-s)!}$

Comment: Hint: Change the direction of the summation to go from $n$ to $0.$

Comment: Apparently the formula you want to prove is wrong. It's $(-1)^s$, not $(-1)^{2s}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks! 
So the book I'm studying made a small mistake, I'll take that into account to try to prove it

Comment: There is also a mistake in the formula for $H_n(x)$ you are trying to use: it's $(2x)^{n-2s}$, and not $(sx)^{n-2s}$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression).